# dictionary iteration in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
users = [
    {'name': 'user1', 'role': ['Consumer']},
    {'name': 'user2', 'role': ['Developer', 'Support Engineer', 'Consumer']},
    {'name': 'user3', 'role': ['UX Designer', 'Architect']},
    {'name': 'user4', 'role': ['Architect']},
    {'name': 'user5', 'role': ['Consumer']}
]
```

I need to iterate above list and print like below:
`[{"role": "consumer", "users": ["user1", "user2"]}]`

Basically reverse the above list, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over your `users`, build an intermediate dictionary, and convert it to your desired `json` format.

```
from collections import defaultdict  

roles = defaultdict(list)
for user in users:
     roles[user["role"]].append(user["name"])

roles_json = [
     {"role": k, "users": v}
     for k, v in roles.items()
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably really easy axis flips available in pandas, but the simple way to do this is:

```py
users = [ ... ]  # your existing list
users_by_role = {}
for d in users:
    name, roles = d['name'], d['role']
    for role in roles:
        users_by_role.setdefault(role, []).append(name)

result = [{'role': role, 'users': users} for role, users in users_by_role.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think this is not about printing. You want to transform your users list into a 'roles' list e.g:

```
def transform_to_role_list(users):
    roles_map = {}
    for user in users:
        for role in user['role']:
            if role in roles_map:
                roles_map[role].add(user['name'])
            else:
                roles_map[role] = {user['name']}
    return [{'role': role, 'users': list(user_set)} for role, user_set in roles_map.items()]

In [1]: transform_to_role_list(users)                                                                                                       
Out[1]: 
[{'role': 'Consumer', 'users': ['user2', 'user1', 'user5']},
 {'role': 'Developer', 'users': ['user2']},
 {'role': 'Support Engineer', 'users': ['user2']},
 {'role': 'UX Designer', 'users': ['user3']},
 {'role': 'Architect', 'users': ['user3', 'user4']}]
```

Note that the roles_map is probably a more useful representation for you (as would be a users map)